# Entity Framework Core 3.0 - Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here below I am using lambda expression in LINQ Includes for 1 level, to fetch a list of customers using three entities, the main one is for all Customers and has only 2 properties Id and bool: IsCompany, the second one has only those that are companies, and the third one has only those that are individuals. The below code was working using .Net Core 2.2, when I updated to 3.0 it stopped working, and most I could find are solutions for multi level such as **Include** -> **ThenIclude** that cannot work here. 
And version [3.0 breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) don't mention this case.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CustomersListVM>>> GetCustomers()
    {
        List<CustomersListVM> customerList = await _context.Customers
            .Include(p => p.Company.Name)
            .Include(p => p.Individual.Name)
            .Select(p => new CustomersListVM
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                CustomerId = p.CustomerId,
                Name = p.IsCompany == true ? p.Company.Name : p.Individual.LastName + ' ' + p.Individual.FirstName
            }).ToListAsync();

        return customerList;
    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I have no explanation for the change, but the way I've been doing multilevel includes is with `Include("Full.Path.ToChild")` and it works fine

Comment: I am using just one level here

Comment: Remove the `.Name` in the Include clauses.

Comment: @James, thanks you, it works, I was including only the properties for performance reason. The response is just a bit slower now, but it works. Please make your answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were looking for multilevel includes. I see now.

Comment: @Sami-L It shouldn't affect performance. Your `Select` clause will cause EF to generate SQL which only selects the `.Name`. However, if performance is critical it may be better to write a Stored Procedure manually.

Comment: Since you are projecting the query results to something you don't need the `Include`s.  You'd only need them if your query was setup to return the entities.

Comment: @juharr what would you suggest to use instead of Includes ?

Comment: @James Stored procedure is a great idea but I can use different database providers, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: @Sami-L I would suggest removing them altogether.  The Select handles the fact that you need to join to the Compay and Individual tables.

Comment: @juharr it works even if I removed, but it looks a bit slower again, have you noticed that I am using a ViewModel "CustomersListVM" rather than the entity ?

Comment: @Sami-L Yeah, which is why the includes are not needed.  You could check to see what the difference is in the SQL, but it's hard to imagine that it would produce something that would run much slower or faster.  Unless Core is doing something stupid like multiple queries, which might be possible.  My company is holding off on switching to Core until they get EF working as well as it does in .Net.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Core might be evaluating the `Select` on the client which means it's going to result in additional queries when yo use the navigation properties without the Includes.  Just horrible.

Comment: @juharr Maybe having Dapper side by side with EF Core on the same query would help to make a comparison..

Comment: You could try a `Select` to an anonymous class with just the required columns, then follow that up with the `Select` that creates the model.  Hopefully in that case EF Core would translate the first `Select` to SQL with the correct joins, and only the columns you need instead of hydrating all the entities.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Include` clause is used to retrieve related objects. The methods should be called with lambdas specifying the linked entities, but without stating `.Name` (because this is a property):

```
.Include(p => p.Company)
.Include(p => p.Individual)
```

Then in the `Select` method, you specify that you only need the `Name` of the company/individual.

Comment: Just from performance point of view, with EF 3.0 version I think it is needed to investigate how to use only the property rather than the whole entity. As it was working as in the question code in 2.2. But thank you for the tip, I am happy it works again.